# Segmentation Fault:11 Error messages in C Terminal

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

While compiling in the terminal I keep getting the error Segmentation Fault: 11. The goal is to make dark circles on a picture of a boarder, ect with command. My reasoning that it isn't working if because of my File IO. I did it without the in & out FILE types and changed the two functions that are called in pgmUtility to not call in files and the program ran smoothly. So I'm assuming I need to have help focusing on the issues I have with my file IO.

Command used:

$ ./a.out -c 470 355 100 < balloons.ascii.pgm > TestImages/balloons_c100_4.pgm

It uses main.c program that relates to pgmUtility.c

This is Main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "pgmUtility.h"

#define ROWS 4
#define COLS 100

void usage(void) 
{
   printf("Usage\n");
   printf(" -h Help Dialog\n");
   printf(" -e edgeWidth < OldImageFile > NewImageFile\n");
   printf(" -c centerRow centerCol radius < OldImageFile > NewImageFile\n");
   printf(" -e edgeWidth -c radius centerRow centerCol < OldImageFile > NewImageFile\n");
   exit (8);

}


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

   FILE *fp;
   FILE *out;
   int i, j;
   int flag1 = 0; //-e switch (edge draw)
   int flag2 = 0; //-c switch (circle draw)
   int numRows, numCols, centerRow, centerCol, radius, edgeWidth;
   char originalImage[100], newImageFile[100];


   char **header = (char**) malloc (sizeof(char*)*4);
   int **pixels;


  //command line argument parsing
  //turn flag switches on or off

   if(argc < 3)
      usage();
   if(argc > 7)
      usage();

   for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {

      if(strncmp(argv[i], "-e", 2) == 0) {
      //set flag on
      //get edge with values)
         if(atoi(argv[i+1]) == 0) {
            usage();
         }
         edgeWidth = atoi(argv[i+1]);
         if(argv[i+2] != NULL) {
            if(atoi(argv[i+2]) != 0) {
               usage();
            }
         }
         flag1 = 1;
      }
      if(strncmp(argv[i], "-c", 2) == 0) {
      //set flag on
      //get radius and center values
         if(atoi(argv[i+1]) == 0) {
            usage();
         }
         centerRow = atoi(argv[i+1]);
         centerCol = atoi(argv[i+2]);
         radius = atoi(argv[i+3]);
         flag2 = 1;
         strcpy(originalImage, argv[5]);
         strcpy(newImageFile, argv[6]);
         fp = fopen(originalImage, "r");
         out = fopen(newImageFile, "w");

      }
      if(strncmp(argv[i], "-h", 2) == 0) {
         usage();
      }

   }

  //allocate memory for header array
   header = (char **)malloc(ROWS * sizeof(char));
   for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
      for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
         header[i] = (char *)malloc(COLS * sizeof(char *));
      }
   }

  //read pgm file
   pixels = pgmRead(header, &numRows, &numCols, fp);
   if(pixels == NULL)
      usage();

   switch(flag1) {
      case 1 :
         if(flag2 == 1) {
         //execute circle draw and edge draw
            pgmDrawCircle(pixels, numRows, numCols, centerRow, centerCol, radius, header);
            pgmDrawEdge(pixels, numRows, numCols, edgeWidth, header);
         }
         else { 
         //execute only edge draw only
            pgmDrawEdge(pixels, numRows, numCols, edgeWidth, header);
         }
         break;
      case 0 :
         if(flag2 == 1) {
         //execute circle draw
            pgmDrawCircle(pixels, numRows, numCols, centerRow, centerCol, radius, header);

         }
         break;
      default : 
         usage();
         break;
   }


  //write new pgm file
   pgmWrite((const char **)header, (const int **)pixels, numRows, numCols, out);

  //Garbage Collection
  //Fix this
  //free(pixels);
  //free(header);

   for(i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
      int *current= pixels[i];
      free(current);
   }
   for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) { 
      char *current = header[i];
      free(current);
   }
   return 0;

}
```

This is two functions from pgmUtility.c that I think may be the cause of the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "pgmUtility.h"

#define ROWS 4
#define COLS 100


// Implement or define each function prototypes listed in pgmUtility.h file.
// NOTE: You can NOT change the input, output, and argument type of the functions in pgmUtility.h
// NOTE: You can NOT change the prototype (signature) of any functions listed in pgmUtility.h

int ** pgmRead( char **header, int *numRows, int *numCols, FILE *in  ){
    int r, c;
  int **array;

  for(r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
    fgets(header[r], COLS, stdin);
    if(header == NULL)
      return NULL;
  }

  //sscanf parses the numRows and numCols
  sscanf(header[ROWS - 2], "%d %d", numCols, numRows);

  //read in pixel map
  array = (int **)malloc(*numRows * sizeof(int *));
  for(r = 0; r < *numRows; r++) {
    array[r] = (int *)malloc(*numCols * sizeof(int));
  }

  for(r = 0; r < *numRows; r++) {
    for(c = 0; c < *numCols; c++) {
      fscanf(in, "%d", *(array + r) + c );
    }
  }
   fclose(in);
  return array;

}


int pgmWrite( const char **header, const int **pixels, int numRows, int numCols, FILE *out ){


//iterate straight through pixels
//setup with a loop to insert a new line every "numCols" and keep printing until "numRows + 1" is reached (as soon as numRows + 1   break loop)
   int i, j;
   for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    //printf("%s", *header[i]);
      fprintf(out, "%c", *header[i]);

   }
    //for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            //fprintf(out, "*I=%d**%s**", i, header[i]);


   for(j = 0; j < numRows; j++){
      for(i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
         fprintf(out, "%d ", pixels[i][j]);
      fprintf(out, "\n");

   }
   fclose(out);
   return 0;



}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to determine where is the Segmentation Fault occurring and then repost the question. And please format your code, it is Irrespectful to pretend that someone would read your code.

Comment: FYI: [Don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @iharob I tried debugging with command lldb but it exits & doesn't let me write commands.

Comment: Your reason for thinking the problem is in the I/O is faulty. If you misuse pointers or write outside the bounds of an array, you get undefined behavior, and it's totally unpredictable which later code will trigger the error. Removing the I/O code doesn't mean that the problem is in the I/O, it just means that you didn't run over the landmines that the earlier heap corruption left.

Answer (score 3):

You're not allocating the `header` arrays correctly. It should be:

```
header = malloc(ROWS * sizeof(char*));
for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    header[i] = malloc(COLS * sizeof(char));
}
```

You had the wrong types in the two `sizeof` calls.

You didn't need the inner `j` loop at all, you were repeatedly assigning to the same `header[i]`.

And for C (but not C++) see: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Also, at the beginning of `main()` you have an extra allocation that you never use or free:

```
char **header = (char**) malloc (sizeof(char*)*4);
```

You should get rid of this.

It's not related to the error, but this is wrong:

```
if(header == NULL)
    return NULL;
```

You should be testing `header[r]`.

For clarity, I recommend rewriting:

```
  fscanf(in, "%d", *(array + r) + c );
```

as:

```
  fscanf(in, "%d", &array[r][c]);
```

Comment: Looking over the answer, I wonder, how many times do you need to allocate each `header[i]`?

Comment: Perfect -- happens to me all the time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It appears (even after correcting the `malloc` call as correctly suggested), you are allocating `header[i]` `COLS` number of times.

```
header = malloc(ROWS * sizeof(char*));
for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
  for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
     header[i] = malloc(COLS * sizeof(char));  // this happens COLS times
  }
}
```

That will leave `COLS` number of each `header[i]` allocated. As I read your code, you need only allocate a single char array for each `header[i]`. To do this, you need to move `header[i] = malloc(COLS * sizeof(char));` outside the `for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++)` loop:

```
header = malloc(ROWS * sizeof(char*));
for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    header[i] = malloc(COLS * sizeof(char));
}
```

You should also validate that `header` and each `header[i]` were successfully allocated.